# How to correct this Build error in public static string GetMessage(string text). GetMessage is underlined

Tags: c#

I am using this code to test. Eventually I want to bind textbox from data table. using sqlDatareader.

```
     public static class Class1
     {

         public static string GetMessage(string text)
         {

             string message;
             int number;
             if (int.TryParse(text, out number))
             {
                 if (number > 10)
                     message = " number must be below 10";
                 else
                     message = " Good ! You entered ; " + number;
             }
             else

                 message = " Not valid Number";
         }

     }


     private void GetParentRecordBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(Class1.GetMessage(Parent.Text));


     }
```

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning anything. Use Return Keyword to return the string

```
public static string GetMessage(string text)
{
    string message;
    int number;
    if (int.TryParse(text, out number))
    {
        if (number > 10)
            message = " number must be below 10";
        else
            message = " Good ! You entered ; " + number;
    }
    else
        message = " Not valid Number";

    return message; // This is the part you missed.
}
```

since `public static string GetMessage(string text)` means your function `GetMessage` is taking one parameter as string and return type is `String`

Comment: Thanks Mohit. It worked. Now I understand how class works. I intend to apply this logic to the following concept.

Comment: Happy to help. Happy Coding Kudos.!! :)